# BPEL: copy array of integers to another array of integers

Tags: arrays, copy, bpel

I have a BPEL process that accepts 2 inputs: `RequestClientID` and `RequestProductsIDList`.
`RequestClientID` is an int that I assign to another int variable, which is the input for a webservice. `RequestProductsIDList` is a list of ints that I have to assign to another list of ints that serves as the input for another webservice.

How do I copy the entire array RequestProductsIDList to the array ProductIDs?

[image]

I am using JBoss BPEL plugin for eclipse. As it is I am copying only the first element, but I need the entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, details here: http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Assigning-an-Array-to-another-in-BPEL-td3007.html

Doesn't actually work straight out of the box, there's still some tweaking to be done, but the general idea holds true.